# make active sentence into passive "He doesn't disturb him."

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

I am having trouble turning these sentences into active/passive voice. I have tried but the active/passive meaning contradicts with the main meaning.

> 1.He doesn't disturb him.(Passive)

Comment: It is good that you have tried! Please tell you *what* you have tried. What was your best try, and why does it contradict the meaning?

Comment: I'm a little confused: the given sentence is marked "passive" but is not.

Comment: Your example is active. The passive version would be "He isn't disturbed by him". Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: Maybe the brackets mean that you are asked to change the sentence _into_ the passive?